# Role of private & non-private initializers in (Dart) private & non-private class constructors?

Tags: oop, dart, constructor

I'm new to OOP currently with intermediate level of understanding. I'm constantly gaining ground by learning Dart and C#. I'm also exploring the design patterns to really understand how it all clicks together based on different scenarios. As for now I'm trying to make sense of following 4 scenarios related to class constructors. I understand the implications of underscore at constructor level and at initializer level. But I am looking for something that may seem quite obvious and clear to experienced programmers out there. Please share your valuable insights as I don't know what I'm missing here.

### Scenario 1: Private Constructor with no initializer

I know this is different from Singleton. Singleton allows single instantiation, this below does not even once. Is there something more to it?

Real World Example:

```
class Firebase {
  // Ensures end-users cannot initialize the class.
  Firebase._();
...
}
```

### Scenario 2: Private Constructor with optional public or non-private initializer

What's the use of this type of private constructor that has non-private initializer (this.app)? Why have a non-private initializer (this.app) in a private constructor?  What is achieved through this?

Real World Example:

```
class FirebaseAuth extends FirebasePluginPlatform {
/// The [FirebaseApp] for this current Auth instance.
  FirebaseApp app;

  FirebaseAuth._({required this.app})
      : super(app.name, 'plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth');

  /// Returns an instance using the default [FirebaseApp].
  static FirebaseAuth get instance {
    FirebaseApp defaultAppInstance = Firebase.app();

    return FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: defaultAppInstance);
  }
...
}
```

### Scenario 3: public Constructor with private initializer

Why have a private property in a non-private constructor? What is achieved through this?

Fictitious Example:

```
class Constructify {
  Map<String,dynamic> _property;
  Constructify(this._property);
...
}
```

### Scenario 4: Private Constructor with private initializer

Why have a private initializer at all when the constructor itself is private?  What is achieved through this?

Real World Example:

```
class FirebaseApp {
  /// A [FirebaseApp] instance can only be accessed from a call to `app()` [FirebaseCore].
  ///
  /// This constructor ensures that the delegate instance it is constructed with is one which extends [FirebaseAppPlatform].
  FirebaseApp._(this._delegate) {
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
  }

  final FirebaseAppPlatform _delegate;
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Asif, welcome to Stack Overflow. As it stands your question is a bit too broad; please focus on one problem or question at time. Here you're asking ~6 separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scenario 1**: `_` in Dart means the variable/method/function/constructor is package private. So as long as we are inside the same package, we are allowed to use the field. So in **Scenario 1** this actually means we can only create `Firebase` objects if we call the constructor from the package where `Firebase` has been declared. This will also prevent you from extending the class in another package since we cannot call the constructor on the `Firebase` class we are extending from.

**Scenario 2**: The package private constructor ensures that objects can only be created by code from the same package. The named `app` parameter is marked `required` so it is not optional. After the object has been created, you can in this case change the `app` variable. I don't know if this makes sense in this scenario but you can do it. I would properly in most cases mark `app` as `final`.

**Scenario 3**: The private field can be set to a value using the constructor but since the field is package private, we can ensure nobody outside our package can access the field afterwards.

**Scenario 4**: A package private constructor is used by some other code in the same package. If you want to ensure only your own package are allowed to create new objects of `FirebaseApp` and don't want code outside your package to get access to the field `_delegate`, you can do what this example does.

Comment: @AsifShaikh No problem. If you don't have any further questions, and thinks my answer do answer all the questions, please accept my answer.